# Is $\langle\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\rangle=A_1+\cdots+A_n$ always true for subsets $A_i$ in ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring(not necessarily commutative or having a unity). Let $A_1,~\cdots,~A_n$ be subsets of $R$. Then is $\langle\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\rangle=A_1+\cdots+A_n$ always true (where $\langle\rangle$ means the ideal generated by the set inside)? I can only find some authors mentioned that if $M$ is a left $R-$module, $S_1,~\cdots,~S_n$ be subsets of $M$, then $\langle\bigcup_{i=1}^nS_i\rangle=S_1+\cdots+S_n$ (where $\langle\rangle$ means the submodule generated by the set inside). But I'm afraid that it might not be true in ring theory.

Comment: What is $\langle - \rangle$ supposed to mean?  Ideal generated by the contents? Subring generated by the contents?  Subgroup generated by the contents?

Comment: @rschwieb Ideal. I have edited. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Even for modules, your claim only works if the $S_i$ are submodules. Consider the case $n=1$.